Same Error code: 1064 while implementing hospital database
When I was working with my hospital database I got these problem
create table MedicalHistory(
  id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  medicaldate DATE NOT NULL, 
  condition varchar (100) NOT NULL,
  surgeries varchar (100) NOT NULL, 
  medication varchar (100) NOT NULL
)


Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'condition varchar (100) NOT NULL, surgeries varchar (100) NOT NULL, medication v' at line 4  0.000 sec

An help would be good

Keywords and Reserved Words

I think condition is a reserved keyword in SQL, you can use backticks to avoid that
CREATE TABLE MedicalHistory(
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    medicaldate DATE NOT NULL,
    `condition` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    surgeries VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    medication VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

